# Mac App Store without admin password?

Tags: mac-appstore

Is there any way to use the Mac App Store without the administrator password? IE change it to install the app at `~/Applications` instead of `/Applications`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one poster in an [Apple discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2711766?start=0&tstart=0), this may be possible in Lion:

> **This is possible with Lion.**
>
> There is a `_appstore` group. All the users that are in this group are
>   allowed to install applications from the Mac App Store.   You can add
>   a user to this group with the **workgroup manager** (install `server
>   admin tool` first). Or by typing in this command on the terminal.
>
> ```
> dseditgroup -o edit -a shortusername -t user _appstore
> ```

Unfortunately, this approach won't work in Snow Leopard or earlier versions of OS X. There also doesn't seem to be an option to install apps in a directory other than `/Applications`.

Comment: OK. I'm on 10.6, and while the admins don't care about apps being installed, they don't like typing in the password for anything non-crucial. So, I guess I'm out of luck.